# Can't see data in my local mongodb but there is no errors and login works fine

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using Nodejs and created login system using passport. Here is my user shema:
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    local: {
        username: String,
        password: String
    }
});
I use url to connect to my local mongodb:
module.exports = {
    'url' : 'mongodb://localhost:27017/loginuser'
}
The thing is that when I register user and try to login and logout it works but when I try to find loginuser database using mongo shell I can't see it at all. Can someone guide me why?

Comment: I suggest you use a db viewer such as MongoChef. It will be easier when you visualize things.

Comment: Don't know what was the reason but after I installed MongoShef I could see the collection.